# Google Form fill from Java

Tags: java, google-forms, autofill

I need to fill basic Google Form from my Java code but it throws `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Unexpected response status: 405`

Here is my code :

```
private boolean sendMessage(UserInfo userInfo) {
    final HttpPost req = new HttpPost("my-form-url");
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

        List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
        form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1301726507", userInfo.getName()));
        form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1466759457", "hello"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);

        req.setEntity(entity);
        System.out.println("Executing request " + req.getRequestLine());

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = response -> {
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                return responseEntity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity) : null;
            } else {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
            }
        };
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(req, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

And here is the form :

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe Post is not defined for this form? That's what the error code states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use my pet project to do the job for you:

1. Add dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.github.stepio.jgforms</groupId>
       <artifactId>jgforms</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Define your form:

   ```
   public enum MyForm implements MetaData {

       USER_NAME(1301726507L),
       MESSAGE(1466759457L);

       private long id;

       JGForm(long id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       @Override
       public long getId() {
           return this.id;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Fill the form and submit:

   ```
   private boolean sendMessage(UserInfo userInfo) {
       URL url = Builder.formKey("my-form-key-from-url")
               .put(MyForm.USER_NAME, userInfo.getName())
               .put(MyForm.MESSAGE, "hello")
               .toUrl();
       Submitter submitter = new Submitter(
           new Configuration()
       );
       try {
          submitter.submitForm(url);
       } catch (NotSubmittedException ex) {
           // TODO: log & handle the exception properly
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Check README and unit tests for more details and examples:

https://github.com/stepio/jgforms